# Chrome fails to start on Ubuntu 20.04 - GPU process exited unexpectedly

Tags: google-chrome, gpu

Suddenly, the chrome failed to load (after updating due to recent patch appears to be available.
GPU process fails? ideas how to fix it?

```
~$ google-chrome
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.227932:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[54683:54708:1014/231535.293972:ERROR:nss_util.cc(357)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.426678:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.567927:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.652461:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.737816:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[54683:54683:1014/231535.819868:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[54683:54683:1014/231535.854194:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[54683:54683:1014/231535.882539:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[54683:54683:1014/231535.909874:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[54683:54683:1014/231535.909927:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 7: 54683 Trace/breakpoint trap   /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real "${@}"
```

Comment: I tried clear the cache  rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
no success 

also version

google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 118.0.5993.70

Comment: when removing and purging chrome stable, it loads with base dev version
Google Chrome 120.0.6062.2 dev
which is higher than the one i installed as stable?